# Does Spark do one pass through the data for multiple withColumn?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Does Spark do one or multiple passes through data when multiple `withColumn` functions are chained?

For example:

```
val dfnew = df.withColumn("newCol1", f1(col("a")))
              .withColumn("newCol2", f2(col("b")))
              .withColumn("newCol3", f3(col("c")))
```

where

- `df` is my input `DataFrame` containing at least columns a, b, c
- `dfnew` is output `DataFrame` with three new columns newCol1, newCol2, newCol3
- `f1`, `f2`, `f3` are some user defined functions or some spark operations on columns like cast, etc In my project I can have even 30 independent `withColumn` function chained with `foldLeft`.

**Important**

I am assuming here that `f2` does not depend on result of `f1`, while `f3` does not depend on result of `f1` and `f2`. The functions could be performed in any order. There is no shuffle in any function

**My observations**

- all functions are in the same stage
- addition of new `withColumn` does not increase execution time in such a way to suspect additional passages through data.
- I have tested for example single `SQLTransformer` with select statement containing all functions vs multiple separate `SQLTransformer` one for each function and the execution time was similar.

**Questions**

- Will spark make one or three passages through the data, once for each `withColumn`?
- Does it depend on the type of functions `f1`, `f2`, `f3`? UDF vs generic Spark operations?
- If the functions `f1`, `f2`, `f3` are inside the same stage, does it mean they are in the same data pass?
- Does number of passages depend on shuffles within functions? If there is no shuffle?
- If I chain the `withColumn` functions with `foldLeft` will it change number of passages?
- I could do something similar with three `SQLTransformers` or just one `SQLTransformer` with all three transformations in the same select_statement. How many passes through data that would do?
- Basically it doesn't matter, the time of execution will be similar for 1 and 3 passages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Will spark make one or three passages through the data, once for each withColumn?

Spark will "make one passage" through the data. Why? Because spark doesn't actually do *anything* when this code is reached, it just builds an *execution plan* which would tell it what to do when `dfnew` is *used* (i.e. some *action*, e.g. `count`, `collect`, `write` etc.) is executed on it. Then, it would be able to compute all functions at once for each record.

> Does it depend on the type of functions f1, f2, f3? UDF vs generic Spark operations?

No.

> If the functions f1, f2, f3 are inside the same stage, does it mean they are in the same data pass?

Yes.

> Does number of passages depend on shuffles within functions? If there is no shuffle?

Almost. First, as long as no *caching* / *checkpointing* is used, the number of passages over the data will be the number of *actions* executed on the resulting `newdf` DataFrame. Then, each *shuffle* means each record is read, potentially sent between worker nodes, potentially written to disk, and then read again.

> If I chain the withColumn functions with foldLeft will it change number of passages?

No. It will only change the way the above-mentioned *plan* is constructed, but it will have no effect on how this plan looks (would be the exact same plan), so the computation will remain the same.

> I could do something similar with three SQLTransformers or just one SQLTransformer with all three transformations in the same select_statement. How many passes through data that would do?

Again, this won't make any difference, as the execution plan will remain the same.

> Basically it doesn't matter, the time of execution will be similar for 1 and 3 passages?

Not sure what this means, but sounds like this is not correct: the time of execution is mostly a factor of number of *shuffles* and number of *actions* (assuming same data and same cluster setup).